# How to configure datasource bean in Spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc

I`m trying to configure a datasource bean in spring, but I always get the same error (properties file not found).

My db.properties file is under src/main/resources.

In my configuration file I have:

```
<bean id="corporateEventDao" class="com.example.JdbcCorporateEventDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
    
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${mysql.jdbcUrl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="db.properties"/>
```

And the error I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/db.properties]
```

I think the problem must be silly, but I can't see it
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I changed de BasicDataSource for DriverManagerDataSource. But the really problem with the properties file was the "classpath".

As I said in my question, it was a silly thing. But it took me 2 hours of work

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcUrl}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
    
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>
```